# Should read-only Boolean grid columns be aligned to center?

Tags: grid, alignment

My understand is text should be left-aligned; dates, times, and numbers should be right-aligned; images should be centered.

What about Boolean strings "Yes"/"No"? My hunch says to center them.

Comment: Heed your hunchthink, I'd do the same and center them since there are only two states (or use a checkmark icon, or a checkbox, etc).

Comment: I think for 508 compliance we have to keep it as Yes/No

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, you can also display boolean values with checkboxes (for editable scenarios) or tick / cross icons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any reason to align "Yes/ No" to right or center just because are booleans.

The numbers are right-aligned to help the reader make easier comparisons of magnitude when scanning down columns.

If this column is important, you can use tags for yes/ no to highlight the info, with different background and the text-centered.

[image]